# MySQL Query Error

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an error with this sentence:

```
...

WHERE title LIKE '%$title%' OR text LIKE '%$title%' 
AND (price BETWEEN $minprice AND $maxprice) 
AND catid = $catid  ORDER BY id DESC
```

**Error:**

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND ) AND cat' at line 34`

I did something wrong?

Comment: a short glance at your expert didn't reveal anything erroneous to me. maybe you should post the full query especially with expanded variables.

Comment: you've got three same answers in less than 40 seconds!

Comment: the $minprice var is empty, when the user don't put a value. I should define a value?

Answer (score 3):

Evaluating `"$maxprice"` gives an empty string, probably because the variable `$maxprice`  it is not defined. It could be a typo, or that you forgot to set a value for this variable.

Comment: Yes It's empty. When the user don't set a value. Should I define a value?

Answer (score 1):

Check your $maxprice Variable - it seems to be empty.